# can i merge the two lists having 10 and 10 elements and created new lists from these two which are the top 10 from these two lists

Tags: scala

1. I have Lists like below these are the lists of windows
   cpu,memory,hosts cpuWin = [10,20,30,40,550,60,70,80,100,30]
   MemoryWin = [23,34,32,45,56,66,55,43,66,76] hostWin =
   [10,20,30,40,550,60,70,80,100,30]

   these are lists of linux cpu,memory,hosts cpuLin =
   [10,20,30,40,550,60,70,80,100,30] memoryLin =
   [23,45,67,78,39,48,57,20,10,30] hostLin =
   [10,20,30,40,550,60,70,80,100,30]

   now i have to merge these corresponding lists of cpus of windows and
   linux , corresponding lists of memorys of windows and linux and
   corresponding lists of hosts of windows and linux  like below....
   now in cpuWin have 10 elements and cpuLin have 10 elements...i have
   sort these two lists and find the top 10 between these two lists and
   same from memory and hosts but i have to sort and find the top 10
   but indexes should not be mismatch becoz same indexes elements are
   related with each other.

Comment: Where is 2.?  There isn't really a question and the entire posts needs formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to tell you to just use a data structure like

```
case class Resources(cpu: Int, mem: Int, host: Int, os: String) {}
```

and put everything into one list, then `masterList.sortBy(_.cpu).takeRight(10)`.

But if you really want to do things with indices, you can.  For example,

```
(0 until 20).sortBy(i => if (i<10) cpuWin(i) else cpuLin(i-10))
```

will give you a list of sorted indices (where you must remember that 10 to 19 refer to Linux).

You will then get three different lists with the top ten taken from each by different criteria.  If you want just one list, you need to decide how to weight the different features.

Note--`sorted` and `sortBy` sort from lowest to highest.  If you want it the other way around, use `reverse` or sort on the negative of the quantity (e.g. `sortBy(- _.cpu)`).

Comment: anybody knows how to use projection in salat mongodb using scala ?